# Query Syntax for Date and Name Structure PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql

Write code to delete row for person named William Smithfield, who was  hired before June 22,2014, and whose job class is equal to or greater than 500.

```
DELETE 
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE EMP_FNAME=William, EMP_LNAME=Smithfield,
AND EMP_HIREDATE<2004-6-22
AND EMP_JOBCODE=>500

 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' EMP_LNAME='Smithfield', AND EMP_HIREDATE<2004-6-22 AND EMP_JOBCODE=>500' at line 3
```

What is the correct syntax for this query?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use single quotes around char and date columns and use AND between conditions like this:

```
DELETE 
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE EMP_FNAME = 'William' AND EMP_LNAME = 'Smithfield'
AND EMP_HIREDATE < '2014-06-22'
AND EMP_JOBCODE >= 500
```

EMP_JOBCODE may also be char and need quotes but I can't tell without your schema. Also you wanted 2014, not 2004

Comment: I am getting a line 5 error at =>500 now, it is closer but still not correct. I tried putting 500 in single quotes.

Comment: Needs to be `>=` not `=>`